# how to search for series of strings in a sentence in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, filter

I have an ArrayList of items. Each item has long strings for example
("The cat is in the hat","It's warm outside","It's cold outside")

what I am trying to do is search for a series of strings for example "It's outside" in any given order in the ArrayList above and it should find 2 of them.

This is what I tried:

```
fun clickItem(criteria: String) {
  productList = productListAll.filter {it: Data
     it.title.contains(criteria, ignoreCase = true) 
  }
} as ArrayList<Data>
```

This works fine when the words I am looking for are in sequence. However, I am trying to get strings in any given order. Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

Comment: The string always contains two words? Or can the string also contain only one word?

Comment: it can definitely contain 1 word but it could contain more than 2 words

Comment: Is the order also important? For example, is "outside It's" not a hit then?

Comment: Is this above your real code or just some pseudocode? I ask because it seems to not be a valid Kotlin code. Also, it should not find any strings in your example.

Comment: Like mentioned before, It could be given in any given order. "outside it's" should also work but only those words and not either or.

Comment: @broot This is a real code. It's just not complete. Data is a data class:

Comment: If I understand correctly, you consider your search string as a set of words (space separated?), and you consider an item in the list to be a match if it contains all the words of the query (in any arbitrary order). Is this correct?

Comment: @Joffrey that's correct.

Comment: Casting to ArrayList is dangerous. There are places in the Kotlin standard library that use other List implementations than ArrayList, in some cases using multiple different implementations returned from the same function depending on the size. You can't assume.

Comment: @Tenfour04 then what do I use instead of ArrayList. I need it to be writable.

Comment: `.toMutableList()` or `toArrayList()`. Alternatively if you need to optimize it, `.let { it as? ArrayList<Data> ?: it.toArrayList() }` will avoid copying the list redundantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by splitting `title` and `criteria` by whitespaces to create a set of words. Then we use [containsAll()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/contains-all.html) to check if `title` contains all of words from `criteria`. Additionally, we need to convert both of them to lowercase (or uppercase), so the search will be case-insensitive:

```kotlin
private val whitespace = Regex("\\s+")

fun clickItem(criteria: String): List<Data> {
    val criteriaWords = criteria.lowercase().split(whitespace).toSet()

    return productListAll.filter {
        it.title.lowercase().split(whitespace).containsAll(criteriaWords)
    }
}
```

Note that searching through text is not that trivial, so simple solutions will be always limited. For example, we won't find "it's" when searching for "it is", etc.